# How to scrape onclick value (<li><a id="FR123456" onclick=) and its name and image using python?

Tags: python, parsing

I got a html string(responseData) with lots of `<li> .. </li>` sets. I want to parse following data from each set of `<li> ...</li>` :

```
1: call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456
2: mango season
3: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png
```

After getting the above data i want to make http request for each url(call.php?category=fruits&fruitid=123456) found an get its result for further processing. Could any one show me how get all above data ?Thanks in advance.

Data sets to scrape :

```
<div id="Category"><span>lists</span><ul>
 <li><a id="FR123456" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123456');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456&amp;',detailFruit,false);">mango season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png">
 </li>



        <li><a id="FR123457" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123457');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123457&amp;',detailFruit,false);">cherry season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123457.png">
                    </li>
 </ul></div>
```

python:

```
url ='http://somewebsite.com/data.php';

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
responseData = response.read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) shipped with python. I will post some code shortly.
For your individual use case, here is some sample code. It is a pretty dump scraper, but I think you should get the gist:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    srces = []
    datas = []
    onclicks = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        for attr in attrs:
            if attr[0] == 'src':
                 self.srces.append(attr[1])
            if  attr[0] == 'onclick':
                  self.onclicks.append(attr[1].split("getit('")[1].split("',")[0])


    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data != " " and not data.startswith('\n'):
           self.datas.append(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(""" <li><a id="FR123456" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123456');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123456&amp;',detailFruit,false);">mango season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png">
                </li>

    <li><a id="FR123457" onclick="setFood(false);setSeasonFruitID('123457');getit('call.php?category=fruits&amp;fruitid=123457&amp;',detailFruit,false);">cherry season</a><img src="http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123457.png">
                </li>"""
)


#To fit your output
for i in range(0,len(parser.srces)):
    print "1: " + parser.onclicks[i] + "\n" + "2: " + parser.datas[i] + "\n" + "3: " + parser.srces[i] + "\n"


#  Output
# 1: call.php?category=fruits&fruitid=123456&
# 2: mango season
# 3: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123456.png

# 1: call.php?category=fruits&fruitid=123457&
# 2: cherry season
# 3: http://imagehosting.com/images/fru_123457.png
```

**EDIT**

To Answer your follow-up question:

```
base_url ='http://somewebsite.com/'
for i in range(0,len(parser.onclicks)):
    url = base_url + parser.onclicks[i][:-1] # use onclick without the last character (&)
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    responseData = response.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for example. How to remove extra "&'" from end of 1: item and how to loop for each parser.onclicks[i] item and make urllib2.urlopen(req)?(response = urllib2.urlopen(req) )?

Comment: Is it possible to put the whole thing inside a function (def myscraper(url)): where  "parser.feed" replaced with data coming from responseData( as shown in my first post responseData = response.read())  ?

Comment: sure, just call parser.feed(responseData)

Comment: I would check in the `handle_starttag` if the tag is a `li`. If so, set some boolean within the class (e.g. `is_li_tag`)  to `True` and to 'False` if the `handle_endtag` is a `li`. Only if the boolean is true, add the data to your lists... Somehow clear?

Comment: Thanks alot . I end up removing those parts from  responsedata now working well ! The only issue i have using urllib2 request inside for loop is slow! Is there any way improve speed ?